# What tools are available to test console applications (I/O) on Windows?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, c#, windows

We have several `exe`s that interact with one another and would like to use something akin to "`Selenium` for Console Apps".  What's available in C# land?

Comment: exes that interact with users or just run and return a success code?

Comment: @Rsf They're console apps - we type stuff in and stuff gets spit out via a cmd prompt.

Comment: With python I know that pexpect is used, try this for c# https://stackoverflow.com/a/29580196

Answer (score 2):

I recommend checking out if there are any command line options that you can use to automate the app. Typically console apps have plenty of them.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511978/run-console-application-in-c-sharp-with-parameters